# What alternatives exist for TVersity and Windows Media Player for a streaming server to XBox 360 and the like?

Tags: streaming, windows-media-player, xbox360

I've tried TVersity, but its interface is a little clunky (being in Flash) and Windows Media Player seems like overkill.

Is there something smaller which gets the job done?

Comment: I can't see past TVersity for streaming media!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to admit you have the best option so far. I use TVersity and I hardly ever need to use the interface. I edit my tags, copy my files into the right folder, and just wait for TVersity to update it's albums.

[XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) is an alternative but also a complete media centre.

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) does allow you to host a stream and has a smaller footprint overall.

Comment: I spose TVersity is alright. It does the job, so I'll stick with it for now. Does anyone else hate the interface?

Comment: I hardly ever use the interface except to add new folders. Never had a real issue with it

Comment: How do you make VLC stream media?

Comment: @Alex. From memory it is under the File menu, there is a broadcast or streaming option. I haven't used it in a while and don't have a copy hand to test, but will update once I am.

Answer (score 5):

[Serviio](http://www.serviio.org/) is a relatively new one.

> Serviio is a free media server. It allows you to stream your media files (music, video or images) to any DLNA-certified renderer device (e.g. a TV set, Bluray player, games console or mobile phone) on your home network.
>
> Serviio uses a priority-based metadata extraction so that you can choose what metadata should describe your media files (e.g. audio track name, DVD cover, TV series and episodes names, etc.). These include metadata embedded into the media files themselves, locally stored metadata files (images, Swisscenter, XBMC, MyMovies) and metadata that can be obtained online. With this powerful tool you will be able to build your Serviio media library easily and effectively.
>
> Serviio enables playback of online resources like RSS feeds so that you can listen to your favourite podcasts or watch latest TV programmes published online.
>
> Serviio works with any DLNA compliant device (TV, Playstation 3, etc.) and some other (XBox 360). It supports profiles for particular devices so that it can be tuned to maximise the device's potential and/or minimize lack of media format playback support (via transcoding).
>
> Serviio is based on Java technology and therefore runs on most platforms, including Windows, Mac and Linux (incl. embedded systems, e.g. NAS).

Amongst a lot of renderers and file formats It supports the following features:

> - streams audio, video (SD & HD) and image files in their native format or transcoded in real-time
> - streams content from online sources, like RSS feeds
> - includes a plugin system to support streaming from non-trivial online sources
> - automatically udpates the media library when you add/update/remove a media file or a metadata file
> - wide array of localized library browsing options
> - supports different editable renderer profiles
> - supports automatic renderer detection and per-IP profile assignment
> - extracts metadata of your media files the way you want it, incl. embedded metadata tags, local metadata files, online metadata sources (in preferred language), XBMC, Swisscenter
> - supports video thumbnails, CD covers, DVD posters, etc.
> - supports external
>     [subtitles](/./index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=33)
> - categorizes video files into movie and/or series and marks last viewed episodes of a series
> - available for Windows, Linux and Mac (with the possibility to run the server part one one platform and console on another)

Comment: I was trying for hours to share some mkvs with my LG smartTV (55LA690) with no success until I tried Serviio. It worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [TwonkyMedia](http://www.twonkyvision.com/), alternatively if you're running [Windows Home Server](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/windowshomeserver/default.mspx), that will also stream media to XBox360 and DLNA certified equipment.

Answer (score 0):

PlayOn I believe is the only one out there with Netflix support, which makes it my favorite.

http://www.themediamall.com/playon